# How i can get Custom types fields group title?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

so my problem is with wordpress and custom types fields plugin.
i want to get the title of group you can see at print screen.. and to show in front end. is that possible?
https://prnt.sc/jhuv8z

Comment: Please check my answer and reply your feedback.

Comment: Hi 

The get_field_objects will return an array of the field group including the id

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_objects/

OR you may use get_field('title');
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get title of field group by:

```
<?php echo get_the_title('6098'); ?>
```

Change the id as per your field group id.